# html svg pattern as brush from path stroke

Tags: javascript, html, svg, path, brush

I am trying to get a pattern (or image or another path) to act as a "brush" for the stroke a path.  I have been able to get a path to in effect act like a clipping region a pattern, but that's not what I want. 
http://jsfiddle.net/honkskillet/Yyx3b/ (THis is what I have so far, not what I want)

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 512 512">
  <defs>
      <pattern id="Pattern" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10">
          <rect fill="gray"  x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
          <path id="testPath" d = "M 000 00 L 50 100 L 100 0"  stroke-width = "5" stroke="black" fill="blue"  />
    </pattern> 

  </defs>

    <path d = "M 200 50 L 300 150 L 200 150 L 200 50"  stroke-width = "20" stroke="url(#Pattern)" fill="red">
    </path>

     <rect fill="url(#Pattern)" stroke="black"  x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>

</svg>
```

I want the pattern (or image or another path) to be oriented and tiled along the direction of the path.  I found a complicated way of doing it in javascript 
http://codepen.io/honkskillet/pen/AIEpF (path on a path)
but I was wondering if there was a pure svg html way of accomplishing this.
Cheers

EDIT

A non-html only solution to drawing a path on a path
HTML

```
<svg id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 512 512">

      <path id="testpath" d = "M 50 400 Q 150 150  50 150  T150 400"  stroke-width = "10" stroke="blue" fill="none" >
    </path>

</svg>
```

Javascript

```
var a = document.getElementById("testpath"),
    len = a.getTotalLength(),
    steps=20,
    p, p1, dp, pa, pb,
    circle;

for(var i =0; i<steps;i++){
    p =   a.getPointAtLength(len*i/steps);
    p1 =   a.getPointAtLength(len*(i+1)/steps);
    dp={x: p.x-p1.x, y:p.y-p1.y};
    pa= {x: (0.67*p.x+0.33*p1.x)-dp.y,  y:(0.67*p.y+0.33*p1.y)+dp.x};
    pb= {x: (0.33*p.x+0.67*p1.x)+dp.y, y:(0.33*p.y+0.67*p1.y)-dp.x};
    circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    circle.setAttributeNS(null,"d", "M"+p.x+","+p.y+" C"+pa.x+","+pa.y+" "+pb.x+","+pb.y+" "+p1.x+","+p1.y);
    //circle.setAttributeNS(null,"d", "M"+p.x+","+p.y+" L"+pa.x+","+pa.y+" L"+pb.x+","+pb.y+" L"+p1.x+","+p1.y);
    circle.setAttribute("stroke-linecap","round");
    circle.setAttribute("stroke-width", "8");
    circle.setAttribute("stroke", "#336699");
    circle.setAttribute("fill", "none");

    document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(circle);

}
```

That will draw a sin curve along a path.

I'd still like a SVG HTML only solution if one exists though.

Comment: Haven't been able to find any HTML only way to do this.  I did hack together a relatively simple Javascript solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you are trying to get a grey and blue zig-zag pattern that follows the line of the stroke, then no, there is no easy/automatic way to do this in SVG.

Comment: Based on my google search research unfortunately I think you are right.  I'll probably accept your answer to but I'll leave the question open for a couple days to see if any comments come in.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pattern id="Pattern" x=".1" y=".1" width=".04" height=".04">
```

Comment: Where are you suggesting I add this in the context of the code snippet?

Comment: fix x, y, width and height values to <1

Comment: That won't do what I want.  I want a pattern/image/path to be tiled along a path.  Like a brush stroke along a path.  Or a zig-zag line that follows the path.